# jquery AjaxSubmit function how to get result from the form page to display

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to understand how to use ajaxSubmit() properly and I'm having some difficulties.  I want to submit my form with ajax and after change the container value to the result echo by the form.   I have an HTML form

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post" id="contact_form" > 
<div id="form-box">
<input type="text" name="name" maxlength="40" >
<input type="submit" name="contact" value="SUBMIT" />
</div>
</form>
```

And then in JS I use the following code to submit the form to `contact.php`

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var options = { 
    success:  showResponse
};  

$('#contact_form').submit(function() { 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
    return false; 
}); 

}); 

function showResponse(responseText)  { 
 $("#form-box").html("Thank you message"); 
}
```

Now, the `#form-box` changes with my "Thank you message" ... but how do I grab what is echo from contact.php after the script is executed?

I'm not sure how to do this and make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be included in the `responseText`, assuming your PHP file is actually outputting something.

Try updating your function to

```
function showResponse(responseText)  { 
 $("#form-box").html("Thank you message"+responseText); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'responseText' parameter contains the response from php file.

```
function showResponse(responseText)  { 
   console.log(responseText);
   $("#form-box").html("Thank you message"); 
}
```